# Problem with adding existing project to solution in VS 2019

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a solution in VS 2019, which already contains two projects. The whole solution is added to version control (Git). If I add some other existing project to my solution, it is not included in the version control repository. How can  I join that added existing  project to the same repository as the entire solution ?

Comment: See, for example, [this tutorial](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/adding-a-file-to-a-repository-using-the-command-line).

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods is to move the existing project ( that we want to add to the solution) files to the solution folder. Then using git command  "git add . " we can add all those files to the solution repository.